# A class with other classes that have only member variables and properties (i.e. No custom Method)

Tags: objective-c, class

I have some structs that I want to use for different purposes in my application. My application needs to define different NSArrays based on each of these structs. Problem is that NSArray doesn't work with structs so I read that I should use classes as objects for NSArray.

Now my classes ( now I will use classes for these structs) are supposed to have just some basic integers and strings and I only need @property probably with them and I don't want to have a lot of .h and .m files in my project each for different class. Is there a way that I can just have one external class and define others as part of it or have all these class definitions in just one pair of .h and .m file? All of these class definitions will be mutually exclusive in functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can have many `@interface` blocks in a .h file, and many `@implementation` blocks in a .m file.

```
// DataTypes.h

@interface Type1 : NSObject

@property (copy) NSString *name; // for example
// more properties

@end

@interface Type2 : NSObject

// more properties

@end
```

.

```
// DataTypes.m

@implementation Type1

@synthesize name;

@end

@implementation Type2

// etc.

@end
```